# bash: find and zip all subfolders of a folder

Tags: bash, zip, recursive

how would one find all subfolders of a folder and zip them separately ?

folder structure

```
./folder  
   -subfolder_1  
   -subfolder_2   
   -subfolder_3
```

expected result:

```
./folder
   -subfolder_1.zip
   -subfolder_2.zip
   -subfolder_3.zip
```

I have tried the following:

```
for i in .; do zip -r $i.zip $i; done;
```

resulted in one **..zip** file containing all the subfolders

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually solution provided by m1k3y02(`for i in *; do zip -r "$i.zip" $i; done`) will work only if current directory contains only subdirectories.

Better way for finding and zipping only subdirectories:

```
for dir in ./* ;do
    if [[ -d $dir ]];then
        zip -r ${dir}.zip $dir
    fi
done
```

or

```
find . -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec zip -r {}.zip {} \;
```

Comment: In the second way, `-mindepth 1` option is needed to exclude the `.` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of tweaks on one of [zuberruber's answers](https://superuser.com/a/933245/2004):

```bsh
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec zip -r --move --test {}.zip {} \;
```

It adds a `-mindepth` test to avoid zipping the current directory, and it puts the global depth tests before the `-type` test to avoid a warning. Also, I added `--move --test` to the zip command so that the unzipped files get removed after successfully being compressed.

Answer (score 0):

solution as follows...

```
for i in *; do zip -r "$i.zip" $i; done;
```